# Is there a better way to use another cell to create a value in Numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I want to avoid using any loop when building a numpy matrix. 
The problem appears when I want to create the third column that should not get the same value than the celle in the same line but second column.
In other word: [Random, Random, Random but not the previous one]

I will later need to make some tests on large files (1.500.000 lines in a GTFS file). If I keep using loops, the math will be slow

```
import numpy as np

T=8
M=np.zeros([T,4])

M[:,0]=np.random.randint(1,4,T)  
M[:,1]=np.random.randint(1,4,T)
for i in range(0,T):
    a=np.array([1,2,3])
    M[i,2]=np.random.choice((a[a!=M[i,1]]),size = 1)#porte retirée

print (M)
```

I would like to replace i by the M[:,1] numpy stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate your random matrix all at once:

```
T = 8000
low, high = 1, 4
np.random.seed(1) # for reproducibility
m = np.random.randint(low, high,(T, 4))
```

Then you can recalculate `m[:, 2]` by adding clipped random numbers to `m[:, 1]` and wrapping those numbers so they stay within [low, high):

```
m[:,2]=(m[:,1]+np.clip(m[:,2],low,high-2)-low) % (high - low) + low
```

Wrapping is done like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696437/6091318)

```
np.any(np.any(m[:,1]==m[:,2]))
# False
```

**Edit # 1**

The above method yields random values for `m[:,2]`, but there is some correlation between `m[:,1]` and `m[:,2]`. Better not to reuse cliped values, just genereate fully random new ones:

```
m[:,2]=(m[:,1]+np.random.randint(low,high-1,T)-low) % (high - low) + low

np.bincount((m[:,2]-m[:,1])%3)
# array([     0, 499972, 500028], dtype=int64)
```

This should be marginally slower, but still just a few milliseconds for one million points in my PC

Comment: This answer is not correct since clipping generates a 2:1 bias in favor of the pattern m_i,2 - m_i,1 = -1 mod 3 over m_i,2 - m_i,1 = 1 mod 3. You can check using `np.bincount((m[:,2]-m[:,1])%3)`